Handle save unsaved changes user choice
I need to handle result of standard "Save unsaved changes" dialog (I want to send some signalr messages on "Yes" and on "Cancel" dialog results).
How can i do it in python script?
I mean this message.


Hello. I think you can use atexit to run custom code just before Blender closes. I don't know if you can reliably catch where the user clicked though. https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html
